# Create widgets for my android application

Tags: android, widget

I need few best links where i can find sample widgets for Sticky notes and reminder widgets with working sample code. I can just find the apk's but not the source code.

Please refer me few codes links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My dear nobody is going to give you a READY code for sticky notes and reminder widgets with working sample code.

But here is a good guidelines for creating android widgets for homescreen: http://www.helloandroid.com/files/xmaswidget/android_howto-hellowidget.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a doubt like., i have a widget button on my screen. When i click the widget button can i (intent) take that to my in build application already installed in my emulator. Please guide me.